# Running spring MVC webApp with hsql: Where is the database file?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hsqldb

I am using SpringRoo to build a webApp and hsqlDB ( InMemory ) As a database. I need to locate the database file that is used. So I can Use a hsqlDb GUI to see the content of my database, Where the hsqldb files are located ?

Comment: `hsqlDB ( InMemory )`: are you sure there is a file for in memory DB?

Comment: No, I'm not. if it doesn't exist, is there a way to show the content of the database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am afraid you cannot do that. Embedded databases are only accessible from within one JVM (at least the ones I know : hsqlDb, Derby, H2). And the content of a memory only database is lost when you close it.

To be able to look at the database content with a GUI, you must use a file backed database, and you will be able to use it only when the webApp is stopped.

For hsqlDb, you can use an Url of (just examples) :

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/databases/hsqldb/mywebapp (for Windows)
jdbc:hsqldb:file:/var/db/hsqldb/mywebapp (for Linux or other Unixes)
```

In those cases, the location of the database is pretty evident :-)

If you want to access to the database **while the webApp is running**, you have to use server mode and start a server before starting the webApp. Example form HSQLB documentation *The following example of the command for starting the server starts the server with one (default) database with files named "mydb.*" and the public name of "xdb". The public name hides the file names from users*

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb
```

You access such a database with following Url : `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb`